# Is it possible to take selector from reselect in epics?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-observable, reselect, epic

I'm using react-observable and reselect in my React project.
All I want to achieve is something like that:

// SELECTORS

```
export const getItem = createSelector(getItemsState, state => state.item);
```

and now in Epics, I want to make something like that:

```
const addItem$: Epic = (action$: Observable<Actions>, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(action => action.type === 'ADD_ITEM'),
    withLatestFrom(state$.select(getItem)), // Just use there my selector which is written.
    switchMap((item) => {
        return ItemsApi.addItem(item);
      },
    ),
  );
```

Is it somehow possible?
Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed how to use it.
So if I want to receive what I've got in selector I need to do something like that:

```
const addItem$: Epic = (action$: Observable<Actions>, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(action => action.type === 'ADD_ITEM'),
    withLatestFrom(getItem(state$.value)),
    switchMap(([, item]) => {
        return ItemsApi.addItem(item);
      },
    ),
  );
```